# Daemon Start at the application bootup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a daemon that should run behind my rails app doing db modifications.I implemented that daemon using ruby daemons gem. I want to start that daemon at the start of my app. Whenever my app starts, I need to start that daemon.

How can I do this..?

Answer (score 2):

If you must start it during Rails initialization:

1. Create a ruby file that will start the daemon. Say `invoke_daemon.rb`
2. Put this file in `config/initializers/invoke_daemon.rb`

However if it isn't mandatory, I would suggest creating a binary executable or a `rake` task and manually starting it through command line. This way it runs as a separate process. You can simply add it to your deployment scripts for production boxes and on development box run it manually. A few examples would be `searchd`, the search daemon for `sphinx` and `thinking_sphinx:delayed_delta` rake task from `thinking_sphinx`.

Answer (score 1):

For your knowledge you have to take look of 
[Rails Life cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696461/rails-applications-life-cycle)

I have just implemented this thing. I have implemented on Windows7.
I have created one batch file let's say **my_batch.bat**, which contains ruby command i.e. **ruby my_daemon.rb** file.
In addition, to execute this file when my app starts , I have just added one statement in environment.rb file which executes that batch file. i.e. system ("my_batch.bat").
But I am not sure that this is a good way to implement this task.